# Using cURL or file_get_contents is empty when calling a Craft page

Tags: plugin-development, plugins

I'm trying to load a page from a Craft based website using file_get_contents or cURL. Using `get_file_contents` I get an empty result, using cURL I can see that the request is getting redirected to the login page.

If I switch to a different domain that is also running Craft the `file_get_contents` and cURL both work fine.

Any idea what could possibly be causing the redirect to be happening?

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution. I needed to set the requireUserAgentAndIpForSession to false,  http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#requireUserAgentAndIpForSession

Seems like having to disable this for a particular url could open up other issues across the board.